# Selecting Date in Xarray Time Series Data

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, time-series, python-xarray

I have an xarray named `wk_conc_avgs` with the following structure:

```
xarray.DataArray'N_CT' juld: 1253 y: 850 x: 994
```

where juld contains dates of structure `"yyyy-mm-dd"`

I am trying to index a particular date by doing this:

```
wk_conc_avgs[juld == ('1997-05-01'),:,:]
```

and I have also tried:

```
wk_conc_avgs[juld == np.datetime64('1997-05-01'),:,:]
```

and

```
wk_conc_avgs.isel(juld=1997-5-1)
```

With the first two attempts, I receive this error: `"IndexError: Boolean array size 1070 is used to index array with shape (1253,)."`
With the latter attempt, I receive this error: `"index 1991 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1253"`

What should I try so I can index the date?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The way to do this is to use:

```
wk_conc_avgs.sel(juld = (np.datetime64('yyyy-mm-dd')), method = 'nearest')
```

Fill in dates as you like. :)